# Nested HTTPWEBREQUESTS in C#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

[HTTPWEBREQUEST 1]https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtL5uCkGy1ERgbEWHlNApMtROuP_0Q

[HTTPWEBREQUEST 2]https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtL5uCkGy1ERgbEXlHjqHdho3lUjfw

When I am trying to call withing main for second time a HttpWebRequest1 and the nested HttpWebRequest2, it runs fine. But on the second run of the nested HttpWebRequest2 I get an exception on THIS line(System.IO.StreamReader sr2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(s2)) on its second run.
Exception:> "Message = "Stream was not readable."

```
try
            {
                HttpWebRequest WebRequestObjectCards = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.ucy.ac.cy/api/v1/cards?status=Valid&");
                HttpWebRequest WebRequestObjectUsers = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("https://api.ucy.ac.cy/api/v1/users/" + ucy_id);


                if (WebRequestObjectCards != null && WebRequestObjectUsers != null)
                {
                    WebRequestObjectCards.Method = "GET";
                    WebRequestObjectCards.Timeout = 12000;
                    WebRequestObjectCards.ContentType = "application/json";
                    WebRequestObjectCards.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                    WebRequestObjectCards.KeepAlive = true;

                    WebRequestObjectUsers.Method = "GET";
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.Timeout = 12000;
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.ContentType = "application/json";
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
                    WebRequestObjectUsers.KeepAlive = true;

                    using (System.IO.Stream s = WebRequestObjectCards.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s))
                        {
                            var jsonResponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; // The value of this constant is 2,147,483,647
                            Students UCYstudents = serializer.Deserialize<Students>(jsonResponse);

                            //String to be added in csv
                            var csv = new StringBuilder();

                            //prepare CSV Header
                            newLine = string.Format("***StartOfFile***");
                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                            newLine = string.Format("ID; FirstName; LastName; RFIDUID; PrintedCardNumber; ValidUntil; Enabled; email; group ");
                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);

                            //deserialize JSON to CSV
                            foreach (var item in UCYstudents.data)
                            {
                                if (item.ucy_id != null)
                                {
                                    ucy_id = item.ucy_id;// used as parameter for WebRequestObjectUsers
                                    ID = item.ucy_id.ToString().TrimStart('0');
                                    RFIDUID = item.card_number.ToString().TrimStart('0');
                                    PrintedCardNumber = item.card_number.ToString().TrimStart('0');

                                    if (item.expiration_date != null)
                                    {
                                        ValidUntil = item.expiration_date.ToString().Replace("-30","-01");

                                        dt = Convert.ToDateTime(ValidUntil);
                                        ValidUntil = ("" + dt.Day + "." + dt.Month + "." + dt.Year);

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        ValidUntil = "";
                                    }

                                    Enabled = "TRUE";

                                    //Getting response from WebRequestObjectUsers
                                  using (System.IO.Stream s2 = WebRequestObjectUsers.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
                                    {
                                        using (System.IO.StreamReader sr2 = new System.IO.StreamReader(s2))
                                        {

                                            serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                                            serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; // The value of this constant is 2,147,483,647
                                            jsonResponse = sr2.ReadToEnd();
                                            Users UCYUser = serializer.Deserialize<Users>(jsonResponse);

                                            FirstName = UCYUser.data.name_en.ToString();
                                            LastName = UCYUser.data.surname_en.ToString();
                                            email = UCYUser.data.mail.ToString();
                                            group = "1";

                                            //Write Fields to CSV File
                                            newLine = string.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5};{6};{7};{8}", ID, FirstName, LastName, RFIDUID, PrintedCardNumber, ValidUntil, Enabled, email, group);
                                            csv.AppendLine(newLine);
                                    ID = "";
                                    FirstName = "";
                                    LastName = "";
                                    RFIDUID = "";
                                    PrintedCardNumber = "";
                                    ValidUntil = "";
                                    email = "";
                                    group = "";

                                            sr2.Close();


                                        }
                                    }

                                }

                            }



                            File.WriteAllText(@".\export.csv", csv.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8);
                        }

                    }
                }


            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: You are probably getting an exception which is not being displayed.  Try adding exception handlers (try/catch) to check for errors.  Often the "using" mask exceptions.

Comment: EndOfStream = 'sr2.EndOfStream' threw an exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException'. Does this help?

Comment: Maybe.  The using disposes the object when you leave the using block.  You have sr2.Close() so you can't dispose an object that is closed.  Try commenting out the sr2.Close() and see what happens.

Comment: Exactly the same errors. Nothing changed. System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean leaveOpen)
   at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(Stream stream)
   at RetrieveUsers.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\RetrieveUsers\RetrieveUsers\Program.cs:line 149

Comment: Maybe use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to check if the request/response sent the 1st time matches the second time.

Comment: [link]https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtL5uCkGy1ERgbEYTboiGClWRjLxgA?e=gwdqyU

Comment: I see just the first and second HTTPwebrequests. The third does not even appear on FIDDLER

Comment: You connection is secured (https).  The first HTTP is non secure where the port number is 443 which is TLS/SSL secure connection.  You are looking at the JSON view.  I would look at the headers which is the same data displayed a little different.  Also look at the response which should be 200 OK.  The code is probably terminating after the 2nd request/response due to an error and that is why you do not see the 3rd request.  Do you see any differences in the 1st request and the 2nd request that you indicate what is wrong?

Comment: This is the first : [link]: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtL5uCkGy1ERgbEZiaX3ikLV_lVfLg?e=2D4fRG

Comment: and this is the second [link]: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtL5uCkGy1ERgbEaePDhsODJNvXhIA?e=dwi3xJ

Comment: Right now I'm blocked from seeing the two links.  Will not be able to see until later.  We need to see the response status code which is in the HTTP from Server to client.  Normally it is 200 OK.   The server may not be sending a response which then we have to verify the connection did not close.  Since HTTP consists of TCP we then look at the TCP layer for a [FIN].

Comment: Can anyone please help me?